# nwjs (node-webkit) modify website javascript and css

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

Is there a way to modify a website javascript/css like we do with Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey but inside my nwjs app? I've made a Chrome extensions that uses the `content_scripts` section in order to run javascript when a certain webpage loads, but I can't find a way to do so in NodeJS with nwjs.

I need to run a few lines I wrote when the end user loads a certain page so things will be modified to match my app window and stuff.

Comment: have you read https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/manifest-format#inject-js-start--inject-js-end - specifically the part about inject-js-start / inject-js-end

Comment: I didn't see anything for match an specific website but good to know there is an option. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I do this very easily with iframes and jquery. Lots of 1 liners to manipulate the remote site. Would you like to see the code I use for that? You can also disable the remote site from breaking out of iframe.

Answer (score 2):

check.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="tgt" src="http://google.com/" style="position:fixed; left:0; right:0; width:100%; top:0; bottom:0;height:100%;" nwdisable nwfaketop>
    </iframe>
    <script src="check.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

check.js

```
var tgt = document.getElementById('tgt');
tgt.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var dom = tgt.contentDocument,
        script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = 'alert(window.location);'
    dom.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

main.js

```
// nothing in here for this test
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Check",
  "main": "check.html",
  "node-main": "main.js",
  "window": {
    "width": 1440,
    "height": 900,
    "position": "center",
    "toolbar": true,
    "title": "Do things now ...",
    "resizable": true
  }
}
```

This successfully injects and runs `alert(window.location);` in google.com

Comment: This one is working. Really help me. I put it inside iframe onload event.